# Update rows where in csv field with MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, select

I have a column in my MySQL table that is filled with comma separated ids.
I wanna update all the rows that have their itemID in the csv list:

```
UPDATE items SET ... WHERE itemID IN(SELECT <csv items id> FROM list WHERE ...)
```

Unfortunately, this only affect the first itemID in the csv list.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT @csv := <csv items id> FROM list WHERE ...;
UPDATE items SET ... WHERE itemID IN(@csv);
```

And it's the same thing, only the first value in the csv list get updated.

Here are some pics to illustrate:
[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Show some of the actual data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest  the use of FIND_IN_SET   (if the result is != then teh ItemID match a value in comma_delimited_string

```
 UPDATE items 
  SET  your_column = your_result
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ItemID, your_comma_delimited_string) != 0;
```

Comment: Do you also know why with my query it only shows the first occurence and not throw an error or something ?